# Hyperledger Fabric: add data to a channel from another one

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Say I have three organisations which are sharing information. A participant in org1 is creating information and wants to share them with a participant inside org2. So it creates a channel between him and that precise participant (in org2). But if later he has to share some of the information shared with the member of org2, also with another member (say in org3)? What's the best way to do so? Is it better to have just one channel and protect the information with Private data? In this case, is it possible to share a Private data with another participant?

[image]